# vscode doesn"t use the python path I gave him, and that it recognize

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I gave to vscode-python my python path, but it doesn't use it to run my .py file, unless in debug mode.... what do I miss ? is it a bug ?

suspected behavior:

- as there is a "py.exe" in the system, vscode relies on it, and ignores the "Python Path" it has in its settings,
- as my winpython is not registered in "py.exe" ... it fails.
- in debug mode, the "python path" is used in the "run" command line and all is ok.
- VSCode Version: 
  Version: 1.37.1 (zip 'Portable' version)
  Commit: f06011ac164ae4dc8e753a3fe7f9549844d15e35
  Date: 2019-08-15T16:17:55.855Z
  Electron: 4.2.7
  Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
  Node.js: 10.11.0
  V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
  OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18362
- OS Version: windows 10

[image]

ok, found the answer: right-click in the in the source, then "run python file in terminal".... sorry for the noise

Answer (score 0):

found the answer: right-click in the in the source, then "run python file in terminal".... sorry for the noise